# how to catch empty text field with multiple insert using php

Tags: php, html, database

I tried to catch the empty text value but it not work. May i have other way for catch empty value? this is my code. Please, help me. Sorry my bad English.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
   include_once 'dbcon.php';
   if(isset($_POST['save_mul'])){       
   $total = $_POST['total'];


for($i=1; $i<=$total; $i++)
{
    $fn = $_POST["fname$i"];
    $ln = $_POST["lname$i"];

    if ($fn = "") {
        alert('Please enter the name');
    }else{
        $sql="INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name) 
          VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."')";
        $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);
    }       

}?>
```

Comment: `alert('Please enter the name');` is JavaScript function.

Comment: You are putting post values inside your sql query in a unsafe way. This is a vulnerability for sql injections.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($fn = "") {
```

You have a assignment inside the expression. What you want is a check for an emtpy string like:

```
if ($fn == "") {
```

Comment: @daro3, In you code this is the main error. Remember `alert()` is java script function. And one more thing this code is not good because except value saved in database all other tasks you can do in javascript in less code.. and that will run faster....

Answer (score 0):

you are using alert which is a javascript function and you are not using comparison operator while checking empty text

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'submit entered'.'<br>';
        if($_POST['name'] == '')
        {
          echo 'enter name';
        }
        else {
        echo $_POST['name'];    
        }

    }

    ?>
    <form method="POST" action="">
      <input type="text" name="name" >
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `empty` for comparison and `echo` for alert message in PHP inside the for loop

```
if (empty($fn)) {
    echo 'Please enter the name';
}else{
    $sql="INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name) 
      VALUES('".$fn."','".$ln."')";
    $sql = $MySQLiconn->query($sql);
}
```